# org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, java-7

I initially started developing with JDK 1.8 version. When using version 1.8, Excel upload and download functions worked without any problem, but after downgrading to version 1.7, the following error occurs.

org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle)

Comment: If you are running on JDK 1.7, all of your application's dependencies need to have been compiled to run on JDK 1.7.  According to https://poi.apache.org/devel/index.html, that means you cannot use POI 4.0 and later ... because they require Java 8 or later.

Comment: I changed it to POI 3.17 and it worked fine! Thank you !!